# Prevent a rich:popupPanel from closing after clicking on a command button

Tags: popup, richfaces

I want my panel to stay visible when i click on a command button and the executed method invokes an error message.

To be more specific I have a validator for an input field which should get a date. If this date is not valid my validate method in the backing bean creates an error message. This should be displayed next to the input field in the popup panel after using the command button.

Clicking on the command button closes the popup though. But if i reopen it, the error message is displayed, making me wonder why it was closed in the first place, when the maximumSeverity condition wasn't met.

My xhtml page:

```
<h:body>
    <h:commandButton id="note" value="Neuer Satz">
        <rich:componentControl target="note_panel" operation="show" />
    </h:commandButton>

    <rich:popupPanel id="note_panel" modal="true" autosized="true"
        resizeable="false" header="Neuen Mehrwertsteuersatz vormerken"
        domElementAttachment="form">
                Gültig ab
                <h:inputText id="newVorGueltigAb"
            value="#{mehrwertsteuerBean.neuGueltigAb}" maxlength="10"
            validator="#{mehrwertsteuerBean.validateNewDate}" />
        <h:message for="newVorGueltigAb" style="color:red" />
        <h:commandButton value="Vormerken"
            action="#{mehrwertsteuerBean.addSteuersatz()}"
            oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) 
                  #{rich:component('note_panel')}.hide(); return false;" />
        <h:commandButton value="Abbrechen"
            onclick="#{rich:component('note_panel')}.hide(); return false;" />
    </rich:popupPanel>
</h:body>
```

My validation method in the backing bean:

```
public void validateNewDate(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate,
            Object value) {
        String regex = "([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{4})";
        String date = (String) value;
        if (date.matches(regex)) {
            validNewDate = true;
        } else {
            validNewDate = false;
            String message = "Bitte gültiges Datum eingeben!";
            context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(context),
                    new FacesMessage(message));

        }
}
```

Comment: h:commandButton has no `oncomplete` attribute.

Comment: Oh, well, thank you!
But if I use a a4j:commandButton another problem comes up:
If I try to submit a wrong date the popup won't close as desired but no error message is displayed.

Comment: You have to render the place where message is. BTW. It will show something only if the validation for newVorGueltigAb will failed. So check out `h:messages` or `rich:messages` for the whole form. BTW2. You have to throw `ValidatorException` if you want validation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you want validation to fail you have to throw an exception. So it must looks something like this:

```
public void validateNewDate(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {
    String regex = "([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{4})";
    String date = (String) value;
    if (!date.matches(regex)) {
        String message = "Bitte gültiges Datum eingeben!";
        throw new ValidatorException(
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, null));
    }
}
```

If you do so there will be no changes in model and the action in your's `commandButton` WON'T be fired. This is the right flow for JSF validation.

Second thing. You have to deal with validation errors manually. To check if there was some error I'm using this:

```
public boolean isNoErrorsOccured() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return ((facesContext.getMaximumSeverity() == null) || 
                (facesContext.getMaximumSeverity()
                    .compareTo(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO) <= 0));
}
```

And with this your `a4j:commandButton` can look like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Vormerken" execute="note_panel"
    action="#{mehrwertsteuerBean.addSteuersatz}"
    render="note_panel"
    oncomplete="if (#{facesHelper.noErrorsOccured}) {#{rich:component('note_panel')}.hide();}
                else { console.log('OMG! I\'ve got an error!'); }" />
```

---

**Update:**

All should look like this:

```
<rich:popupPanel id="note_panel" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false"
    header="Neuen Mehrwertsteuersatz vormerken" domElementAttachment="body">
    Gültig ab
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="newVorGueltigAb" value="#{mehrwertsteuerBean.neuGueltigAb}" maxlength="10"
            validator="#{mehrwertsteuerBean.validateNewDate}" />
        <h:message for="newVorGueltigAb" style="color:red" />
        <a4j:commandButton value="Vormerken" execute="@form" action="#{mehrwertsteuerBean.addSteuersatz}"
            render="@form"
            oncomplete="if (#{mehrwertsteuerBean.noErrorsOccured}) {#{rich:component('note_panel')}.hide();}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Abbrechen"
            onclick="#{rich:component('note_panel')}.hide(); return false;" />
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Note:

- Missing `<h:form>`!!!
- The `render` attribute, because you have to render your panel in case of validation error.
- There are no brackets at the end of `action`.
- The `execute` attribute is set to popup only. This will cause that no other fields from the whole form will be updated.
- Since `h:form` is inside the popup I've changed `domElementAttachment` to body.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Emil, but it still doesn't work with your code. At first I just copy-pasted it into my page resulting in the popupPanel not closing even if I typed in a correct date. Furthermore the error wasn't displayed. If I close the panel with the other button "Abbrechen" and reopened it the message is displayed.
Then i removed some attributes and tried to break the problem down and it seems that the execute und render attributes together prevent the panel from closing even if the date is valid.
Why the message isn't rendered immediately, I can't tell.

Comment: In addition I found out, that when clicking on the "Vormerken" button the console shows the following error:
TypeError: RichFaces.$(...) is undefined

Comment: I usually don't do this, because it looks like you have to learn JSF first, but I updated my answer. I works out of box. Just copy-paste it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i really appreciate your efforts. But even when I copied your new code it just won't work.
It seems like the oncomplete script isn't even executed because I've used your else condition from above and the console doesn't display it when the condition isn't met. Furthermore it gives out the following error each time i click the button:
`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Change the text for console. It missing `\` before `'`. That's all. I forgot to change it.

Comment: Thanks, that killed the error message! 
But it still won't work. The note panel just closes now regardless of my input. And there is no message shown even when I reopen it.

Comment: Previously you said you got an error in JavaScript in `else` part so there is no way popup is closing if `else` i fired. I've just copy-pasted my code to bean, added getter and setter plus empty action and it works like a charm. Don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I think it was messing with the formatting resulting in the whole command being rendered useless.
Well, thank you for your help anyway, maybe it's about the versions we use, I can't tell.